# How to add loader for Observable in Ionic 3 app?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, observable

I'm new in development world and faced a problem that I can't solve. I'm building Ionic 3 app and trying to implement all my request as Observables. And I want to add simple spinner while app is fetching data from cache or server. My code:

home.ts

```
homeMenu$: Observable<Array<any>>

ngOnInit() {
  this.homeMenu$ = this.backend.getHomeMenu()
  .pipe(
    catchError(err=> {
      this.utils.presentToastError(err)
      return [];
    })
  )
}
```

home.html

```
<ion-item *ngFor='let item of homeMenu$ | async'>
  {{item.title}}
</ion-item>
```

How can I add a spinner into `ngOnInit()` to handle when data was applied to `this.homeMenu$` variable (either success or error);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Thanks **Ciprian B** for idea, but unfortunately it appears that we can't call function or block of code in pipe() just like that. I found work around:

home.html

```
 <ion-spinner name="bubbles" *ngIf="showSpinner"></ion-spinner>
```

home.ts

```
  homeMenu$: Observable<Array<any>>
  showSpinner = false

  ngOnInit() {
   this.showSpinner = true
   this.homeMenu$ = this.backend.getHomeMenu()
   .pipe(
    tap(()=> {this.showSpinner = false}),
    catchError(err=> {
      this.showSpinner = false;
      this.utils.presentToastError(err)
      return [];
    })
  )
```

}

if with an error case all was clear, with success case we have to use tap() operator to call any function or block of code after observable emits the result.

Answer (score 0):

First of all declare a new variable for eg. `showSpinnerAdd = false`, next at the begining in the ngOnInit add `this.showSpinner = true`. You will have something like this:

```
//declare
showSpinner = false;

ngOnInit() {
  this.showSpinner = true
  this.homeMenu$ = this.backend.getHomeMenu()
  .pipe(
    this.showSpinner = false;
    catchError(err=> {
      this.utils.presentToastError(err);
      this.showSpinner = false;
      return [];
    })
  )
}
```

then in html file:

```
<div id="spinner" *ngIf="showSpinner"></div>
<ion-item *ngFor='let item of homeMenu$ | async'>
  {{item.title}}
</ion-item>
```